# Toggle QPen for selected items after QGraphicsScene selection change

Tags: python, selection, pyside, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

How can I toggle the QPen color for the selected graphicsview items? Ideally I would like to handle this color change in the graphicsview or graphics scene objects rather than directly handling it in the main windows selection event.

Any help is appreciated. Currently it will turn the pen color white when the object is selected. I'm not sure how to turn it back avoiding looping through all objects.

Is there a way i could add a function in the MyGraphicsView class itself that would handle the color change of the pen for any and all selected items in the graph?

**Update: More detailed information**
Here is a list of the selection issues I'm trying to resolve:

1. When a user clicks and makes a selection rectangle it should deselect all items, restoring them to their default Pen color. The newly selected items should have a white Pen color. If the user is holding control it should add the newly selected items. If items are already selected and the rectangle crosses over them, it should still keep them selected.
2. If a user clicks in a negative area where no item appears under the cursor, it should clear the current selection.
3. If a user clicks on an item it should select it and make the Pen color white.
4. If the user is holding control it should always add to the selection.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import random


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self._isPanning = False
        self._mousePressed = False
        # self.setBackgroundBrush(QImage("C:/Users/jmartini/Desktop/Temp/images/flag_0140.jpg"))
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )


    def mousePressEvent(self,  event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._mousePressed = True
            if self._isPanning:
                self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
                self._dragPos = event.pos()
                event.accept()
            else:
                super(MyGraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._mousePressed = True
            self._isPanning = True
            self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self._dragPos = event.pos()
            event.accept()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._mousePressed and self._isPanning:
            newPos = event.pos()
            diff = newPos - self._dragPos
            self._dragPos = newPos
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - diff.x())
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - diff.y())
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self._isPanning:
                self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            else:
                self._isPanning = False
                self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            self._mousePressed = False
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._isPanning = False
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            self._mousePressed = False
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event): 
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        pass


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space and not self._mousePressed:
            self._isPanning = True
            self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)


    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            if not self._mousePressed:
                self._isPanning = False
                self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)


    def wheelEvent(self,  event):
        # zoom factor
        factor = 1.25

        # Set Anchors
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)

        # Save the scene pos
        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Zoom
        if event.delta() < 0:
            factor = 1.0 / factor
        self.scale(factor, factor)

        # Get the new position
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Move scene to old position
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


class MyGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self,  parent):
        super(MyGraphicsScene,  self).__init__()
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(50,50,50)))
        # self.setSceneRect(50,50,0,0)


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.gv = MyGraphicsView()
        self.gv.setScene(MyGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gv)

        self.gv.scene().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed)
        self.populate()


    def populate(self):
        scene = self.gv.scene()

        for i in range(500):
            x = random.randint(0, 1000)
            y = random.randint(0, 1000)
            r = random.randint(2, 8)
            rect = scene.addEllipse(x, y, r, r, QPen(QColor(255,128,0), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin), QBrush(QColor(255,128,20,128)))
            rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable )
            rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable )

        rect = scene.addEllipse(300, 500, 20, 20, QPen(QColor(255,128,0), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin), QBrush(QColor(255,0,0,128)))
        rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable )
        rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable )


    def selection_changed(self):
        selection = self.gv.scene().selectedItems()
        print 'Selected:', len(selection)
        for i in selection:
            i.setPen(QPen(QColor(255,255,255), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: could you explain me better

Comment: From what I understand you want that if an item has been selected, change your QPen to white, and if you reselect that same item you should return to the previous state. I am right?

Comment: When the item is selected it changes to White, and if that item is de-selected it should return to it's original color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to get the required behaviour by caching the last selection and then clearing it before making the new selection:

```
class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.setScene(MyGraphicsScene(self))
        self.scene().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed)
        self._current_selection = []

    def select_items(self, items, on):
        pen = QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255) if on else QColor(255, 128, 0),
                   0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
        for item in items:
            item.setPen(pen)

    def selection_changed(self):
        try:
            self.select_items(self._current_selection, False)
            self._current_selection = self.scene().selectedItems()
            self.select_items(self._current_selection, True)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass
```

Here is the complete script:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import random


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self._isPanning = False
        self._mousePressed = False
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
        self.setScene(MyGraphicsScene(self))
        self.scene().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed)
        self._current_selection = []

    def select_items(self, items, on):
        pen = QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255) if on else QColor(255, 128, 0),
                   0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
        for item in items:
            item.setPen(pen)

    def selection_changed(self):
        try:
            self.select_items(self._current_selection, False)
            self._current_selection = self.scene().selectedItems()
            self.select_items(self._current_selection, True)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

    def mousePressEvent(self,  event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._mousePressed = True
            if self._isPanning:
                self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
                self._dragPos = event.pos()
                event.accept()
            else:
                super(MyGraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._mousePressed = True
            self._isPanning = True
            self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self._dragPos = event.pos()
            event.accept()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._mousePressed and self._isPanning:
            newPos = event.pos()
            diff = newPos - self._dragPos
            self._dragPos = newPos
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - diff.x())
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - diff.y())
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self._isPanning:
                self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            else:
                self._isPanning = False
                self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            self._mousePressed = False
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self._isPanning = False
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            self._mousePressed = False
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        pass


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space and not self._mousePressed:
            self._isPanning = True
            self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)


    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            if not self._mousePressed:
                self._isPanning = False
                self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        else:
            super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)


    def wheelEvent(self,  event):
        # zoom factor
        factor = 1.25

        # Set Anchors
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)

        # Save the scene pos
        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Zoom
        if event.delta() < 0:
            factor = 1.0 / factor
        self.scale(factor, factor)

        # Get the new position
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Move scene to old position
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


class MyGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self,  parent):
        super(MyGraphicsScene,  self).__init__()
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(50,50,50)))
        # self.setSceneRect(50,50,0,0)


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.gv = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gv)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        scene = self.gv.scene()
        for i in range(500):
            x = random.randint(0, 1000)
            y = random.randint(0, 1000)
            r = random.randint(2, 8)
            rect = scene.addEllipse(x, y, r, r, QPen(QColor(255,128,0), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin), QBrush(QColor(255,128,20,128)))
            rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable )
            rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable )

        rect = scene.addEllipse(300, 500, 20, 20, QPen(QColor(255,128,0), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin), QBrush(QColor(255,0,0,128)))
        rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable )
        rect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable )


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this partially works. doesn't seem to update when using the Drag Select rectangle and it only works if i select the item twice. It doesn't toggle the color back to its original color unless i click it twice.

Comment: @JokerMartini. Hm - you didn't mention any of those extra requirements in your question. Can you please make sure you give details of **all** the behaviour you expect before I attempt another solution?

Comment: Of course i can do that :), it was my fault for assuming others would know im expecting default selection behaviors to be applied.

Comment: @JokerMartini. I see you've added a small edit, but it doesn't really clarify anything. For example, what exactly do you expect to happen when dragging a selection rectangle, if it includes items that are in a mixture of states? And a similar situation can occur when making a multiple selection via ctrl-click.

Comment: @JokerMartini. I have updated my answer with a new solution. It seems to work okay, but I haven't tested it to destruction...

Comment: when i drag the rect selection their border color does not appear to change.. its getting closer though :)

Comment: @JokerMartini. Works fine for me - are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: @JokerMartini. I've now tested it pretty thoroughly, and can confirm it all works exactly as expected. The only minor issue was some runtime errors when closing the app if there was a cached selection (which I've now fixed in the code example).

Comment: what does your mousePressEvent look like. you had previously edited that.

Comment: @JokerMartini. I just used your example script, without any of the previous changes. For clarity, I have now added the complete, fully working script to my answer.